# How to reset primary Outlook alias back to my Hotmail ID

Tags: account-management, outlook.com

I want to change the Primary Alias for my mail account back to the original Hotmail ID (I had added an Outlook ID and set it as Primary Alias).

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

To be able to change your primary alias, take the following steps:

1. Go to https://account.live.com which contains your account summary, etc.
2. On the left menu, click on `Overview > Account aliases`
3. There is a list of your associated accounts. Change away :)

[image]

Answer (score -2):

You can't, you have to wait 30 days I believe.